# Need some clarification and critiques regarding a Bower, Grunt, and Bootstrap workflow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm, bower

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed Bower globally via npm
2. Installed Grunt globally via npm
3. Created a working file folder ("test")
4. Created a bower.json (I realize bower init would have worked just as well) with "bootstrap": "latest" as the only dependency
5. cd ~/test
6. bower install --save (save flag is unnecessary, as the dependency was predefined, I guess)
7. cd bower_components/bootstrap
8. npm install
9. grunt

Here are the impressions that I've come away with (please correct me if any of the following is wrong):

- I've set up a working environment in which my JS and LESS will be automatically linted, compiled, and minified upon running "grunt dist" (or grunt, but I gather that this is less efficient).
- All of my working HTML files should be placed directly into the "dist" folder.
- Bower will take care of dependency upgrades without overwriting modified files.
- Upon completion, my site/Bootstrap template may be registered with Bower for effortless recreation.

I have a few questions:

a) Do most of this workflow's users create a new working environment for each project, or just maintain one set of working files and modify the gruntfile, dist folder, and custom LESS/JS folders/files?

b) A follow-up to the previous question: do most Bootstrap users modify core components directly, or just try to add custom LESS/JS files and folders? Would a core modification be overwritten upon bower update-ing to a new version of BS?

I am very new to web development. I apologize for the rather excessive post. If there's a better place for me to interface with just a few patient folks who are willing to put up with me asking further questions, please point me there (I've gotten most of my programming-related questions answered on Stack in the past, so I came here first). I know that Stack is generally geared toward very specific questions and answers.

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked but you might want to look at Yeoman, and learn how to use generators. Bassically a generator let's you bootstrap a working environment in just a few clicks. There are a ton of really good generators, you could use one of those or create your own. I am sure that you can find one that suits the workflow you are looking for.

Comment: I'll check Yeoman out! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Typically you want to make custom files for your css/less files and even js files. I usually make the barebone minimum bootstrap / angular build and customize / delete as I need to.

B) If you make a new file and save it in a directory, make sure it's not where all your dependencies are. If you update via Bower, the updating files could be deleted. It's good practice to make a content / scripts or css folder and put your custom styles / scripts in it.

Hope that answers it

Comment: In reference to A), that makes sense to me.

However, what do you mean when you say "if you update via grunt"? I didn't think grunt would overwrite anything - just bower, upon executing bower update if a new version of bootstrap is released. What are you referring to when you say "it's also good practice to do that too"?

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for pointing that out. I was actually referring to Bower. If you update any dependencies (angular, bootstrap, etc) via Bower it will replace those files (and any within that directory ) and update them with the new one. Also when you were asking if most users update the core, I was stating as good practice measure its better to make a new file and add any custom classes / scripts you make in there.

Comment: Thanks! That's all helpful, and I appreciate the update to your original answer. I think now I'll just need to start tinkering and breaking things in order to figure out exactly how I'd like to handle my folder structure and workflow. I was under the impression that there was a correct way to handle everything we've discussed here (which is true, but only to a degree), but it seems that specific configurations are best determined on a case-by-case basis rather than universally.